# QGIS 2.8.1 Consult a space object and to lead me to a specific folder

Tags: qgis

Folders display in QGIS clicking on an item.

I need you to click on a space object redirect me to a desired folder.

[image: Deseo que al hacer click sobre el objeto me redireccione a la carpeta contenedora]

In the picture above I can only link a file and other achievement to take me to him, but I want to redirect me to the containing folder and not to the file.
The action you tried is as follows: [this action does not run as the achievement desire] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvjtW.jpg)
And to clarify have done the command in tiny, I mean, in the action field have placed "= ** explorer [%" Route "%] **"

I relied on this information, but what I want is to open the folder where the image is located. [Http://mappinggis.com/2015/04/mostrar-imagenes-en-qgis-al-hacer-clic-sobre-un-elemento/](http://mappinggis.com/2015/04/mostrar-imagenes-en-qgis-al-hacer-clic-sobre-un-elemento/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you already have the folder name on the attribute `Ruta` and the action defined. You already did the most difficult part.

Maybe there is some small problem with your action. Your action must be of type Windows. Check my screenshot, which is running fine. It opens the folder as expected.

[image: Action to open file explorer on a folder]